# Feynman self-energy diagrams

Tags: electrons, quantum-electrodynamics, feynman-diagrams, virtual-particles, self-energy

In the Feynman picture, I don't understand how virtual photons in the self-energy diagram for a rest-frame electron can have energies that exceed $2m_e$. Aren't negative energy states of the electron supposed to propagate backwards in time ? If so, then wouldn't the re-absorption have to be prior to the emission, thus violating causality. Alternatively, if one takes the Dirac Sea interpretation of the vacuum, then the negative energy states are all occupied and therefore can't be scattered into, so one has the same apparent problem.

I am sure there is a simple answer to this, but it completely escapes me.

Comment: You shouldn't take Feynman diagrams as literal space-time diagrams. The electron propagator can be off-shell, in which case it doesn't violate energy momentum conservation to have high energy photons

Comment: I know that 4-momentum is conserved at each vertex. My question concerned the threshold beyond which the transient intermediate state of the electron (in its initial rest frame) has negative $k_0 = m_e - \omega$.

Comment: There is nothing wrong with negative $k_0$ in the propagator in a loop. This is the Fourier transform of a field, not the energy of an actual particle.

Comment: But Feynman diagrams represent particle, not field, histories, with each edge being labelled by a 4-momentum. Also see my edit re Dirac sea.

Comment: No, they very much represent field behavior, not particle behavior.  It is not accurate to think of an internal line in a Feynman diagram with a far off-shell momentum as having anything like particle-like behavior.

Comment: A diagram represents an amplitude, one of infinitely many, and if you sum all of these you get a description of real world events. It is entirely valid to associate particular diagrams with particular real world phenomena. This is possible because the simplest diagrams correspond to the largest effects. For example Coulomb scattering, bremsstrahlung and pair annhilation. They each have their own leading order diagram and you don't need to bring in QFT to get amplitudes that can be compared with experiment. No one seems to be interested in the original question though.

Comment: But you are considering loop diagrams. Your question is based on an incorrect understanding of Feynman diagrams.